# IIS Rewrite Rule for Web.conf with in application

Tags: iis, coldfusion, web-config

I have two applications of ColdFusion. Their folders are parallel to each other like this:

```
...SiteA
...SiteB
```

SiteA is the main the site in IIS. I am running SiteB by creating application in SiteA.  The requirement is that:

- `sitea.com` should point to the SiteA folder.
- `sitea.com/b/` should point to the SiteB folder.

Most of the code in SiteB is running through the query string. Like if `cgi.query_string` is `store=b`, then it will work efficiently.

I need a rewrite rule for this purpose. I want to keep the `web.config` file in the SiteB folder.  I have tried following but it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>

                <rule name="Rewrite for b">
                 <match url="^b/$" />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.cfm?store=btn" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone please help with this rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to keep web.config in the root folder and reference all files from that folder. Why dont you want to keep siteB folder inside siteA folder? It would solve half the confusion. If for some reason you cant keep siteB inside siteA, I would suggest that you have a folder called siteMain inside which you can keep siteA, siteB and web.config. So you can follow any of the two approaches:

- siteMain

  - siteA
  - siteB
  - web.config

OR

- siteA

  - siteB
  - web.config